# How to prove $f_n \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was trying to build a scheme to solve this kind of question:

*Let $D$ be a domain of $\Bbb R^n$ and $f_n\colon D \to \Bbb R$. Say if $f_n \in L^1(D)$*.

First of all I need to check that both $f_n$ anf $f:=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n$ $\in L^1(D)$ and in that case the only possible limit for $f_n$ in $L^1(D)$ is $f$.

After that step I think to know just this 3 ways:

1. use the definition and solve (or compare) the integral $\int_D \left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|dx$: in this case the $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_D \left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|dx$ should be $<+\infty$ or $0$?;
2. use the monotone convergence theorem and check that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_D \left|f_n(x)\right|dx < +\infty$;
3. if the dominated convergence theorem can be applied to the $f_n$ I have the convergence.

Is that right? Have you any other hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Do you want to show $f_n \in L^1$ or $f \in L^1$, where $f $ is the (pointwise) limit of the $f_n $ or do you want to show $\|f_n -f\|_1 \to 0$?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly. The exercises I've to deal with are of this type: *Let D be a domain of $\Bbb R^n$ anf $f_n$ : D $\to$ $\Bbb R$, with $f$ depending on a parameter $\alpha$. Say for which $\alpha$ $f_n \in L^1(D)$*.

Comment: I think that first of all I've to understead when $f_n \in L^1(D)$ so I was trying to check with you if the 3 points I've written above are correct.